# Magento 2 : How do conver price from any currency to base currency?

Tags: magento2, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

I am converting price from any other currency using currency code to base currency and for this I am using this method :

```
$oldCurrency = 'AUD';
$newCurrency = 'USD';
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data');
$priceHelper->currencyConvert($item->getCustomPrice(), $oldCurrency, $newCurrency);
```

My base currency is USD and `USD to AUD` conversion rate is defined in admin.

When I am converting price from `USD to AUD` then its working, but when I am trying to convert price from `AUD to USD` then it gives me error that conversion rate is not defined.

**How do I convert price from any currency to any other currency ?**

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 6):

> **NOTE: In the example the amount in current store currency is
>   converting to amount in base store currency.**

You can use this code to convert one currency to another:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory
 */
protected $currencyFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
}

/**
 * Convert base price value to store price value
 *
 * @param $amountValue
 * @return float
 */
public function convertPrice($amountValue)
{
    $currentCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
    $baseCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();
    if ($currentCurrency != $baseCurrency) {
        $rate = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currentCurrency)->getAnyRate($baseCurrency);
        $amountValue = $amountValue * $rate;
    }

    return $amountValue;
}
```

The `$currentCurrency` and `$baseCurrency` variables can be replaced by any valid currency codes from the currency collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup AUD in store allow currency

> Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Allowed
>   Currencies - Select AUD and USD and save.

Now you can see your currency rate here

> Admin >> Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates >> Import >> Save
>   Currency Rates.

Now you can check your custome currency contvert code.

Comment: These all things are already done and default currency converter is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

> For converting any currency, your currency must be in the allowed currency
>   Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Allowed Currencies
>
> Your currency rate must be set in currency rates 
>   Admin >> Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates

Magento Directory provides conversion from Base currency to any other currency.
But if you want to convert currency from any currency, then you can use Magento **`\Magento\Directory\Model\Currency`** class.

```
 /**
 * constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
) {
    $this->currency = $currency;
}


/**
 * convertCurrency.
 * @param  string $from
 * @param  string $to
 * @param  float $amount
 */
public function convertCurrency($from,$to,$amount){
    if($from == $to)
        return $amount;
    $this->currency->load($from);
    $rate = $this->currency->getAnyRate($to);
    return $rate*$amount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means it cannot find the correct rate. I would suggest going to Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates and  click on Import button which should resolve your issue if the rate has been selected in the system config

Comment: These all things are already done and default currency converter is working properly.